# Cleanly passing a list of arguments to ProcessStartInfo

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process, command-line-arguments

Arguments are received as `string[]` in a fresh program. They are already parsed correctly, so quotes will keep a parameter together, even though it may be a path that contains spaces. Nice.

I now want to forward them to a new `Process`, but `ProcessStartInfo` only supports `string` to define arguments.

So, just concatenating them with spaces is wrong, as paths may then be split into multiple arguments. I'm also unsure if wrapping them in quotes and then concatening them with spaces works in every instance - I don't think so, as the target program may not see `-u` and `"-u"` as equivalent. Is there a clean way to do this in .NET Framework?

Comment: [It's all in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getcommandlineargs?view=net-6.0#remarks) And .Net 5+ supports `ProcessStartInfo.ArgumentList`

Comment: @Charlieface This does not answer the question. I know how it works for a concrete case. But I'm asking how it works in the general case, maybe there already is code I can use that will sanitize the arguments properly.

Comment: The documentation for [`ProcessStartInfo.Arguments`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments?view=netframework-4.8) does state that for .net programs `A single argument that includes spaces must be surrounded by quotation marks, but those quotation marks are not carried through to the target application.` This actually means if you're passing the arguments to a C# program, `"-u"` and `-u` will both be seen as `-u`,  even though it doesn't contain any spaces.

Comment: @AyCe *(to Charlieface) This does not answer the question* - yep, that's why it's a comment..

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes, I know that. But I am not passing to a C# program.

Comment: It's impossible to answer if you don't know how the process parses command-line arguments with spaces and/or quotes. In theory a process could treat `"-u"` the same as `-u` but treat `"-t"`  differently from `-t`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Even so, just putting quotes around isn't the proper solution. At the very least, you would need to add another level of escaping to the string you want to wrap in quotes, as that string may of course contain quotes itself. Now I could write a function to do this (and later discover that I forgot something), or there could already be an existing function that takes care of this. I am looking for an existing function, and if there isn't one, an approach to handling this that is better than this one I just came up with.

Comment: You misunderstand what I was saying - I meant that you can't solve this at all in the general case at all if you don't know how the process parses its arguments.

Comment: For example, a particular process might want arguments containing spaces to be enclosed in single quotes, or in parenthesis. You just wouldn't know, because the only argument that actually gets passed to a process at the Windows API level is a single string, and the Windows API doesn't prescribe how a process should parse multiple arguments from a single string.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I think I already understood that, but it's not a problem for my case.

Answer (score 3):

`ProcessStartInfo` also has an [`ArgumentList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.argumentlist?view=net-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.6.2#System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_ArgumentList) property which allows for passing multiple arguments.

> `ArgumentList` and the `Arguments` property are independent of one another and only one of them can be used at the same time. The main difference between both APIs is that `ArgumentList` takes care of escaping the provided arguments and internally builds a single string that is passed to operating system when calling `Process.Start(info)`. So if you are not sure how to properly escape your arguments, you should choose `ArgumentList` over `Arguments`.

[Reference](http://ArgumentList%20and%20the%20Arguments%20property%20are%20independent%20of%20one%20another%20and%20only%20one%20of%20them%20can%20be%20used%20at%20the%20same%20time.%20The%20main%20difference%20between%20both%20APIs%20is%20that%20ArgumentList%20takes%20care%20of%20escaping%20the%20provided%20arguments%20and%20internally%20builds%20a%20single%20string%20that%20is%20passed%20to%20operating%20system%20when%20calling%20Process.Start(info).%20So%20if%20you%20are%20not%20sure%20how%20to%20properly%20escape%20your%20arguments,%20you%20should%20choose%20ArgumentList%20over%20Arguments.)

---

### EDIT

Applies to

| Product | Versions |
| --- | --- |
| .NET | .NET 5, .NET 6, .NET Core 2.1, .NET Core 2.2, .NET Core 3.0, .NET Core 3.1 |
| .NET Standard | 2.1 |

Comment: The question is for .NET Framework.